# Script to Monitor IPMI SEL in real time

Tags: bash

I want to monitor IPMI System Event Log(SEL) in real time. What I want that is that whenever a event is generated in SEL , automatically a mail alert should be generated .

One way for me to achieve this is that I can write a script and schedule it in cron. The script will run 3 or 4 times a day so whenever a new event is generated , a mail alert will be send to me.

I want the monitoring to be active. Like whenever a event is generated , a mail should be sent to me instead of checking at regular intervals.

The SEL Log format is as follows:

server-001% sudo ipmitool sel list

b4 | 05/27/2009 | 13:38:32 | Fan #0x37 | Upper Critical going high

c8 | 05/27/2009 | 13:38:35 | Fan #0x37 | Upper Critical going high

dc | 08/15/2009 | 07:07:50 | Fan #0x37 | Upper Critical going high

So , for the above case whenever a new event is generated , automatically a mail alert should be send to me with the event. 
How can I achieve this with a bash script . Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you include in your question either your cron script or the lines from it that check for an event and email you?  I'm not sure how far back and forth my answer needs to go.  Also, please remove the 'Thanks' line from question; it's not done

Comment: I have edited by query to add the log format.

Comment: Albert Chu's answer looks good so I'm not going to write one.  Note that via /etc/rsyslog.conf you can say to put a subsystem's messages in a specified file (ie can keep its messages separate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe some vendors have special extensions in their firmware for exactly what you are describing (i.e. you just configure an e-mail address in the service processor), but I can't speak to each vendor's support.  You'll have to look for your motherboard's documentation for that.

In terms of a standard mechanism, you are probably looking for IPMI PET (platform event trap) support.  With PET, when certain SEL events are generated, it will generate a SNMP trap.  The SNMP trap, once received by an SNMP daemon can do whatever you want, such as send an e-mail out.

A user of FreeIPMI wrote up his experiences in a doc and posted his scripts, which you can find here:

http://www.gnu.org/software/freeipmi/download.html

(Disclaimer: I maintain FreeIPMI so I know FreeIPMI better, unsure of support in other IPMI software.)

As an FYI, several IPMI SEL logging daemons (FreeIPMI's ipmiseld and ipmitool's ipmievtd are two I know) poll the SEL based on a configurable number of seconds and log the SEL information to syslog.  A mail alert could also be configured in syslog to send out an e-mail when an event occurs.  These daemons are still polling based instead of real-time, but the daemons will probably handle many IPMI corner cases that your cron script may not be aware of.

Comment: Thanks Albert for the pointers. That will really help me to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring of IPMI SEL events can be achieved using `ipmievd` tool . It is a part of `ipmitool` package.

```
  # rpm -qf /usr/sbin/ipmievd
   ipmitool-1.8.11-12.el6.x86_64
```

To send SEL events to `syslog` , execute the following command.

```
   ipmievd sel daemon
```

Now , to simulate generation of `SEL` events , we will execute the following command.

```
   ipmitool event 2
```

This will generate the following event

```
   ` Voltage Threshold - Lower Critical - Going Low`
```

To get the list of SEL events that can be generated are , try

```
 # ipmitool event

 usage: event <num>
 Send generic test events
 1 : Temperature - Upper Critical - Going High
 2 : Voltage Threshold - Lower Critical - Going Low
 3 : Memory - Correctable ECC
```

The event will be notified to /var/log/messages. Following message was generated in log file.

```
Oct 21 15:12:32 mgthost ipmievd: Voltage sensor - Lower Critical going low
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anyone else...

I created a shell script to record data in this format, and I parse it with php and use google's chart api to make a nice line graph.
2016-05-25 13:33:15, 20 degrees C, 23 degrees C
2016-05-25 13:53:06, 21.50 degrees C, 24 degrees C
2016-05-25 14:34:39, 19 degrees C, 22.50 degrees C

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE=`date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`
temp0=$(ipmitool sdr type Temperature | grep "CPU0 Diode" | cut -f5 -d"|")
temp1=$(ipmitool sdr type Temperature | grep "CPU1 Diode" | cut -f5 -d"|")
echo "$DATE,$temp0,$temp1" >> /events/temps.dat
```

The problem I'm having now is getting the cron job to access the data properly, even though it's set in the root crontab.